# Is it possible to revert only block of code changes of a commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, atlassian-sourcetree

So I am working with `Visual Studio Code`, and `Sourcetree`.

Let say I do have a file named **Occupation.ts**

**Occupation.ts** (*Initial Commit*)

```
private getOccupationCategoryTable(index: number): string {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 1: return 'occupationCategoryLookUpCommon';
        case 2: return 'occupationCategoryLookUpCreditCard';
        case 3: return 'occupationCategoryLookUpASB';
    }
}

private saveOccupationTable(index: number): string {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 1: return 'saveOccupationCategoryLookupCommon';
        case 2: return 'saveOccupationCategoryLookupCreditCard';
        case 3: return 'saveOccupationCategoryLookupASB';
    }
}

private updateOccupationTable(index: number): string {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 1: return 'updateOccupationLookupDetailCommon';
        case 2: return 'updateOccupationLookupDetailCreditCard';
        case 3: return 'updateOccupationLookupDetailASB';
    }
}
```

Now I made some changes with this file.

**Occupation.ts** (*Latest Changes*)

```
private getOccupationCategoryTable(index: number): string {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 1: return 'occupationLookUpCommon';
        case 2: return 'occupationLookUpCreditCard';
        case 3: return 'occupationLookUpASB';
    }
}

private saveOccupationTable(index: number): string {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 1: return 'saveOccupationLookupCommon';
        case 2: return 'saveOccupationLookupCreditCard';
        case 3: return 'saveOccupationLookupASB';
    }
}

private updateOccupationTable(index: number): string {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        case 1: return 'updateOccupationLookupDetailCommon';
        case 2: return 'updateOccupationLookupDetailCreditCard';
        case 3: return 'updateOccupationLookupDetailASB';
    }
}
```

So I made changes on `getOccupationCategoryTable`, and `saveOccupationTable` functions. Now I wanted to revert my changes only in `getOccupationCategoryTable`. Is there any `git` way to achieve this?

Comment: You could try `git reset -p`

Comment: git does not work with file differences. It works with different files. The whole file. Use a merge tool to merge the two files, edited, staged or committed. `git difftool`

Comment: @marblewraith if I try this, it will revert all the changes, I am just trying to revert a block of code.

Comment: @rioV8 meaning to say, it is not possible?

Comment: @Rich No, that's what the `-p` flag is for.

Comment: `git help reset`: `-p` Interactively select hunks in the difference between the index and <tree-ish> (defaults to HEAD). The chosen hunks are applied in reverse to the index.

Comment: interesting question

Answer (score -1):

Revert the bad commit and pass the `-n` flag. This should create a new commit, but it will stage those "undo" changes. Next, a simple `git reset` will unstage those changes, then use SourceTree to selectively undo chunks within that file:

1. `git revert -n <Commit Id>`
2. `git reset`
3. Open SoureTree and select the modified file
4. Stage chunks that "undo" the bad code.
5. Commit.